# Is there a way, value defined in one main controller, can be accessed from all the other spring mvc controller?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Something like this:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  public String getCurrentUserDetails() {
    String username = "testuser";
    return username;
  }
}

@Controller
public class DashboardController { 
  @RequestMapping("/admin/dashboard")
  public ModelAndView showDashbard() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("username", GET username FROM HOME CONTROLLER [HomeController's getCurrentUserDetails]);
    modelAndView.setViewName("/admin/dashboard");
    return modelAndView;
  }
}

@Controller
public class ProfileController { 
  @RequestMapping("/admin/profile")
  public ModelAndView showProfile() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("username", GET username FROM HOME CONTROLLER [HomeController's getCurrentUserDetails]);
    modelAndView.setViewName("/profile/dashboard");
    return modelAndView;
  }
}
```

Yes I know I can instantiate the HomeController and get the object. But making object in every controller is hectic.
I just want the value of one controller available in all other controllers.

Comment: Don't just don't. If you want a variable available in all the models (basically always) either use an `@ControllerAdvice` or a `HandlerInterceptor` instead.

Comment: You could also use a `@Session` component, update it whenever `getCurrentUserDetails()` is called and inject it where you need it. If you're using Spring Security, you can get the credentials as well from `SecurityContextHolder`.